# Updating D3 Map with Dynamically Generated JSON Data

Tags: javascript, json, d3.js

I have a D3 map where circles represent both a quantity (size of circle) and a percent value (color of circle). All of this is generated when the page loads, and within the interface is a jQuery UI slider that allows the user to cycle through a time series in the data - which changes both the size of the circle and the color. To change the size, I've created a function within jQuery's slider like so:

```
slide: function( event, ui ) {
redraw(ui.value.toString());

function redraw(val) {
  g.selectAll("circle")
  .transition()
      .duration(1000).ease("linear")
      .attr("r",  function(d) { return radius(+d[val]); });
     }
}
```

And this works great. I am also dynamically calculating percent like so:

```
var percent = [];
   table.forEach(function(d) {
   percent [d.city]=(d[ui.value])/d.total;
})
```

Where both 'city' and 'total' are fields within the loaded csv file. I would like to join these percent values to the data then change the colors of the circles as the slider is slid. Both the csv and the percent array both contain the city name, so I imagine I can use this to perform the join, I'm just uncertain how.

Comment: Just use the same code you're using to set the colour in the first place.

Comment: Okay, I got it. I my .style to fill the circles, I just needed it to look like the following: .style("fill", function(d){
    if (percent[d.city] <= .249)
     return "#ffffb2";    - Linking the city name to the percent that is generated.